# How do I modify a literate haskell script to contain unicode characters?

Tags: vim, text-editors, unicode, haskell

I would like to modify a .lhs file currently written in plain text. For example, -> would be replaced by → in the .lhs file. I am aware that for display purposes, many text editors can replace these on the display, but I am keen to replace the contents of the file itself. Is there a script that can do this automatically?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

yes there is the [unilatex.vim](https://github.com/epsilonhalbe/dotfiles/tree/master/vim/ftplugin/tex) plugin (i already disabled the conversion back to latin1 chars) and a haskell prettyfy plugin i merged this [haskell.vim](https://github.com/epsilonhalbe/dotfiles/tree/master/vim/ftplugin) from many haskell.vim plugins i found online. In the haskell version the code gets converted back to normal code on saving - but you can just comment out this part.
Maybe you have to change a bit of the code to associate the plugins to literate haskell files - i only tried them with plain haskell.

But I don't know if the .lhs file will compile if you change the -> to the arrow.